# Multi-threaded java server used for a buzzer beater?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, server, client

In Java is there a way to connect multiple clients to a server at once without creating multiple threads? I want to create a buzzer-beater for a trivia game I'm making for my friends and I. However, I don't want the server to only be listening to one thread (or contestant) at a time. I'd like the server to be constantly listening to all clients and track the order in which they each hit the button on the client GUI I made.

Not looking for specific code, just ideas. Is a multi-threaded server even the right approach for this sort of problem? Is there a better networking solution in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, use Netty or vert.x.  Just remember - don't block the main thread.

Comment: Handling individual connections in separate threads is not uncommon. Depending on the amount of connections you might need to start thinking about resource limitations, however, for a small project you should be fine.

Comment: You could check out [Multicast Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html). I haven't worked with them in a long time, but I do believe there's a way to get information back to the server as well